# Android get temperature reading from a BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to get temperature reading from a BLE device.

I read the document produced by the BLE device vendor.

- Characteristics UDID：2A1C
- Properties: Indicate
- Characteristics Name:Temperature Measurement
- Data Format: 0xFE000D97 (34.79 Celsius)

First I would like to get the data 0xFE000D97 from the BLE and this data should be a characteristic with INDICATE PROPERTY. However, I tried a free app called **B-BLE** and also the **sample BlueleGatt code from Android Developer**, both of them cannot get the data.They can only get characteristic with READ, WRITE or Notify properties.

Can anyone tell me how to get the data or provide some sample code?

Next step I have to keep track of the data. i.e. I need to update the temperature measurement by setCharacteristicNotification(). However, now I can't even get the first reading....

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you set the property on the characteristic to be "Read" instead of "Indicate"?

My Android implementation can read characteristics from BLE device if the characteristic property is set as "Read". 
Sorry, but I am not aware what "Indicate" does.

Comment: Indicate works just like notify but with the addition of an ack back from the client to the server after the attribute has been received successfully by the client. In general notify and indicate are push-type delivery of data to the client, compared to a normal read which is a poll

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example how to decode the reading, the following worked for me on a device.

```
FE000D97 is little endian you should convert it to 
big endian 97 0D 00 FE
FE is the exponent = 254 which is 256-254=2, therefore  x 10^-2
97 hex = 71 decimal
0D hex = 13

00 : sometimes has no meaning and sometimes is 0x256x256, which is also the same =0
```

temp = 71 + 13x256 + 0 x 256x256 = 3399
now divide temp/100 = 33.99

Normally, this should have a notification property, there is a sample [code](https://os.mbed.com/teams/Seeed/wiki/Analog-Temperature-Sensor)